# Android: cant get variable through get method

Tags: java, android

I want to use set and get methods in my android app.
In MainActivity.java if i click button i want to set my email variable in UserEmail.java and then get it from PostEmail.java and make toast. But in this way, my toast is empty. If i copy this toast to my MainActivity.java, its working.

Code error is

> int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void clickButton(View v) {

        String myEmail = "myemail123@gmail.com";

        UserEmail userEmail = new UserEmail();
        userEmail.setEmail(myEmail);
    }
}
```

UserEmail.java

```
public class UserEmail {

    public String email;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

PostEmail.java

```
public class PostEmail extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        UserEmail userEmail = new UserEmail();
        Toast.makeText(this,userEmail.getEmail(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: In the `PostEmail` activity you are just creating a new `UserEmail` object and trying to show a toast of the email property, which is null. You should probably send the `PostEmail` activity your already existing `userEmail` object when you call `startActivity`. (By implementing parcelable in the `UserEmail` class)

Comment: Finally i found right solution i wanted, if i put static before variable in UserEmail, then its working! Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are initializing UserEmail object in your PostEmail Activity without setting its email value (like you do in your MainActivity), so his email String is null.

Comment: Didn't know UserEmail objects were male. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should send the "email" throught an Intent, something like this:

```
public void clickButton(View v) {

    Context context = v.getContext();
    String myEmail = "myemail123@gmail.com";

    Intent i = new Intent(context, PostEmail.class);
    i.putExtra("EMAIL", myEmail );

    startActivity(i);

}
```

And at your PostEmail Activity, you should do this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String email = getIntent().getStringExtra("EMAIL");
    Toast.makeText(this,email,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

When you do `UserEmail userEmail = new UserEmail();` at your `onCreate` method you are creating a new UserEmail instance, that's why you can't get the email, that you have setted before.

In other words the variable `userEmail` from MainActivity and the `userEmail` from PostEmail are not the same instance.

Comment: Yep, in this way it is working but if i don't want to startActivity , then i cant use that.

Comment: @j22purikas well you still can use sharedpreferences to share information, check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Answer (score 0):

josemgu91 is correct.

But it looks like you want to make UserEmail a field in MainActivity or in a global singleton class instead of in the clickButton method. Then either make that field a public singleton or make a getter that returns the UserEmail var or UserEmail var.getEmail()

or use guisantogui 's suggestion and pass the value using intents, but I would do it in a separate method, not in a cliclListener.